# Are these exponential forms equal?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

Is  $(\frac1{\sqrt x})^{11}$? the same thing as $x^{\sqrt{11}}$ ?

Basically what I'm asking is are those equivalent/the same?

Comment: Let $x=4$ then is $\frac{1}{2^{11}}=4^{\sqrt{11}}$?

Comment: I don't get how to do square root exponents though. @dustin

Comment: Use a calculator if need be.

Comment: Not even $\sqrt{x}^{11}$ equals $x^{\sqrt{11}}$, cannot move the square root from base to exponent.

Answer (score 2):

$$\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\right)^{11} = \left(x^{-1/2}\right)^{11} = x^{-11/2} \neq x^\sqrt{11} = x^{11^{1/2}}$$ So for equality you would need $\frac{-11}{2} = \sqrt{11}$ which is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Those are not the same. $\left(\frac1{\sqrt x}\right)^{11}=(x^{-1/2})^{11}=x^{-11/2}$.

Comment: How does (1/vx) = (x^−1/2)

Comment: Well $x^{-n}=\frac1{x^n}$ and $x^{1/2}=\sqrt x$. Too see the second part, square both sides. So $\frac1{\sqrt x}=\frac1{x^{1/2}}=x^{-1/2}$.

Answer (score 0):

We don't need an analytical approach to disapprove this equality. If we can find a counter example for $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ where the left doesn't equal the right, we will be done. Take $x$ to be $4$. Then $\frac{1}{2^{11}}\ll 1$. The right hand side $4^{\sqrt{11}}\gg1$. So the equality doesn't hold. Another approach would be to take a significantly large $x$. Then the left hand side goes to zero and the right hand side goes to infinity.